# How do you render and filter over a collection of data from an @argument?

Tags: ember.js

This question comes from our [Ember Discord](https://discord.gg/emberjs)

---

I have something like this

```
{{#each @data as |project|}}
  <ItemList @categories={{project.category}}/>
{{/each}}
```

I am calling action somewhere else, then filtering the @data and I would like to reset this `each @data`.

I want to assign the filtered result to `@data`
data passed from parent component to this

At the same component I have button

```
<li 
  class="inline hover:underline cursor-pointer ml-4" 
  {{on "click" (fn this.changeProject project.name @data)}}
>
  {{project.name}}
</li>
```

and `changeProject` action filters the @data that I would like to re-assign to #each
for example - `this.data = filteredModel;` does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your action, `changeProject` looks something like this:

```js
@action
changeProject(projectName, data) {
  this.data = data.filter(project => project.name.includes(projectName));
}
```

the observation that `this.data` doesn't work is correct and intended, as `@data` is available at `this.args.data`, but every key on `this.args` is immutable.

so, in your component, in order to reference filtered data, maybe you want to create an alias:

```js
get filteredData() {
  return this.args.data;
}
```

and in your template:

```
{{#each this.filteredData as |project|}}
  ...
```

and then your action would need to be updated as well because we *still* can't set `filteredData` *or* `this.args.data`

```js
import Component from '@glimmer/component';
import { tracked } from '@glimmer/tracking';
import { action } from '@ember/object';

export default class Demo extends Component {
  @tracked filtered;

  get filteredData() {
    return this.filtered ?? this.args.data;
  }

  @action
  changeProject(projectName) {
    this.filtered = this.args.data.filter(project => project.name.includes(projectName));
  }
}
```

```
{{#each this.filteredData as |project|}}
  <ItemList @categories={{project.category}}/>
{{/each}}

...
<ul>
  {{#each @data as |project}}
    <li 
      class="inline hover:underline cursor-pointer ml-4" 
      {{on "click" (fn this.changeProject project.name)}}
    >
      {{project.name}}
    </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```